# does core data create a database for you?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios4

does core data create a database table for you? I am new to core data and iphone programming and all the tutorials that I see bring in a pre populated database. I am trying to create an app that saves data (i.e. Dates and times) and I don't need to use a prepopulated database. I was wondering when you check the box to use core data, does it create an empty database for you or do you have to create a database table with all the empty fields you need and bring in that sqlite file? This probably sounds like a newb question but I appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it creates a table for you. You don't need to mess with such these things.
Here is the best starting tutorial: [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html)
When you know these informations, then you can head and learn more from other tutorials. You will have a different look at them.

Answer (score 0):

You specify a filename. If the file doesn't exist (typical first time your app is run on a device) an empty database is created. If the file exists it will be loaded. You wouldn't really want to try to prepopulate some data in there using SQL. The database has to have a specific, unpublished format for Core Data. If it doesn't match there would be an error.